# Drivers for a Intel Desktop Board D865GSA

Tags: software-installation

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed in my desktop. There is no other operating system installed. Do I need to install my motherboard drivers too (LAN driver, Audio Driver, Graphics driver)?

If yes then where I can get these drivers for "Intel Desktop Board D865GSA" that can be installed in Ubuntu 12.04, as the installation files that I am having are in .exe format which I am unable to install in Ubuntu.

Comment: Why do you need a motherboard driver?! You will need a Graphics driver, that can be done easily without downloading anything else: run `software-properties-gtk` and then chose which driver.

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't have to use your Windows drivers.
(Linux based OS-es like Ubuntu doesn't use Microsoft's drivers.)

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 12.04, generally all the necessary drivers are installed automatically and there is no need to manually install them. However, sometimes the display driver still needs to be installed manually. You can do this by opening up System Settings... and clicking on Additional Drivers. The application shows you the possible drivers you can install.

The real question would be, is there anything that is not functioning properly? If not, then there's no need to worry about manually installing additional drivers.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need anything else.
If you are experiencing problems with your hardware, you may want to search for proprietary drivers, if available. To do this, go to System Settings and click on Additional Drivers.

Answer (score 1):

Your motherboard D865GSA has been discontinued by Intel.

Since Ubuntu comes with many out-of-the-box drivers and `generic drivers`; theirs no need to install drivers as such.
 You many want to install drivers only if some of your motherboard component is not working properly or not being detected.

You can have your motherboard's drivers from [Intel support page](http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support), under the 
 **Discontinued Products > Desktop Boards > 865 Chipset Family > Desktop Board 865GSA**

Here's the Intel support link [specifically for your MotherBoard](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Desktop%20Boards&ProductLine=Intel%C2%AE%20865%20Chipset%20Family%20Boards&ProductProduct=Intel%C2%AE%20Desktop%20Board%20D865GSA) 
unfortunately Intel is having majority windows related drivers, thus you may want to select "OS Independent" category.

> If you are not experiencing any problem then you don't need to install
>   any drivers. Ubuntu supports majority of the old n new hardware.

Comment: If you want, you can also get proprietary drivers for your hardware. Search them under ""System Settings > Additional Drivers""